# Incorrect parsing of html in the community bulletin

Tags: bug, status-completed

It appears that the community bulletin isn't correctly parsing html:

[image: Hey! Whoa! What's that weird ' ish?]

*Using IE 10 on a Win 7 Enterprise*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already reported on [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197133/special-characters-just-broke-in-the-community-bulletin/197134#197134) and fixed.